# Getting started with RequireJS and Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I am new to both Backbone and Require JS.

I am receiving the following error:

> Cannot read property View of undefined.

So Backbone is not available, but I cannot see where the problem is.  Any help would be much appreciated.

I have the following 3 files:

#### index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script data-main="boot" src="../libs/require/require.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">Magic!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### boot.js:

> ```
> require.config({
>   baseUrl: "../",
>   paths: {
>       jquery : "libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min",
>       underscore : "libs/underscore/underscore-min",
>       backbone : "libs/backbone/backbone-min"
>   }
> });
>
> require( [ "app/views/app" ], function(AppView) {
>   var app = new AppView();
> });
> ```

#### app.js:

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "underscore",
    "backbone"
    ], function( $, _, Backbone ) {

    var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $( "#main" ),
        initialize: function () {
             this.render();
        },
        render: function() {
            this.el.html("huzzah!");
        }
    });
    return AppView;

});
```

Comment: You should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944672/cannot-read-property-view-of-undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need to shim backbone in order for it to work with requirejs.

From the [RequireJS docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim):

```
requirejs.config({
    shim: {
        'backbone': {
            //These script dependencies should be loaded before loading
            //backbone.js
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            //Once loaded, use the global 'Backbone' as the
            //module value.
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, in its own file and it gets included directly from the html. I usually call it 'config.js'. TodoMVC has an excellent example of using backbone and require.

http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/dependency-examples/backbone_require/